# como hago para que mi slider se detenga por cierto tiempo en cada elemento?

Tags: html, css, slider

Mi slider se mueve sin pausas, como hago para que pause, creo que el problema son los porcentajes del @key frame porque al modificarlos para agregar otra imagen dejo de hacer pequeñas pausas, también si quito los porcentajes de la ultima imagen en css hace pausas y hasta se ve mejor así que añadí otro y se ve bien pero como le hago para que haga las pausas con 5 y no 6.
Ya intente agregar mas tiempo pero simplemente tarda mas en cambiar de elemento en elemento y no para hacer pausas

```css
.slider-img{
    height: 600px;
    width: 1000px;
}

.slider {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: none;
}
.slider ul {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    width: 500%;
    animation-name: cambio;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-duration: 25s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite ;
}
.slider li {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    }
.slider img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
@keyframes cambio {
    0% {margin-left: 0;}
    20% {margin-left: 0;}
    
    20% {margin-left: -100%;}
    40% {margin-left: -100%;}
    
    40% {margin-left: -200%;}
    60% {margin-left: -200%;}
    
    60% {margin-left: -300%;}
    80% {margin-left: -300%;}

    80% {margin-left: -400%;}
    100% {margin-left: -400%;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="slider">
        <ul>
          <li><img src="ej1.jpg" alt="1"> </li>
          <li><img src="ej2.png" alt="2"></li>
          <li><img src="ej3.jpg" alt="3"></li>
          <li><img src="ej4.jpg" alt="4"></li>
          <li><img src="ej5.jpg" alt="5"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: nomas quiero que haga pausas ya se que es mucho texto lo que puse arriba